# how to create vpn profile in android programmatically

Tags: android, vpn

im using api 10 in eclipse.i want to make an app to create just a simple vpn profile that is available in phone settings.

i searched alot but i couldn't find a solution.

i read that i should use VpnProfile as below...but i couldnt find it and this code gives error...

```
    VpnService service = context.getSystemService(VPN_SERVICE);
    VpnProfile profile = VpnProfile.create(L2TP_PROFILE);
    profile.setName(myServerName);
    profile.setServerName(myServerAddress);
    profile.setRouteList(“192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0,192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0”);

    service.connect(profile, myUserName, myPassword);
    service.setNotificationIntent(myIntent);
```

i appreciate you if you can help me...
thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @commmonsWare thsnks...but your comment doesn't related to my question

Comment: couldn anyone answer me ???

Comment: "but your comment doesn't related to my question" -- yes, it is related. You wrote "this code gives error". The question that I linked to shows you how to examine the Java stack trace associated with your error, and it also points out what to include in your Stack Overflow question in order to get help with your programming problems.

Comment: but i mean in eclipse it gives error that the class not found !!!!

Comment: `VpnService` does not exist on API Level 10. And I have no idea what `VpnProfile` is, as I do not see it in the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare, it's an Android 4.2.2 Parcel-like entity class for VPN profiles.  I believe it was taken out after 4.2.2.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/net/VpnProfile.java

FaridFaa, this is why it can't find your class, you're most likely building for a newer target and this class won't exist in anything > 4.2.2

Sorry, i'm a bit late on the reply. ha

Comment: Have you found any good solution??